# Angular js does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my html file. The angular.js file is under java/main/webapp/js folder and Intellij can see it when I click on it, yet the code does not work! I get a print on screen {{helloMessage}} and not "hello world"

What am I missing here?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Angular test </title>

</head>
 <body>

<h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{helloMessage}}</h1>

Angular test 
<script src="js/angular.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function HelloWorldCtrl($scope){
       $scope.helloMessage="Hello World";
  }

</script >

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah that pluralsight video ain't right... maybe it's outdated?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You forgot [`ng-app`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp) , put it in the `body` tag:

```
 <body ng-app>
```

Have a look at [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/F5uLevaZxg6oe9ovMwwF?p=preview).