# AngularJS application not working

Tags: angularjs

I start with AngularJS. Try create easy app, but dont working.

```
<div class="col-md-10 editor" ng-controller="Editor">
          {{hello}}
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Editor', function($scope) {
   $scope.hello = "Hello!"; 
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

In console dont have errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular js does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923859/angular-js-does-not-work)

Comment: he want to use controller in AngJS

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the app in your Html file as well.

Something like:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
</body>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-10 editor" ng-controller="Editor">
          {{hello}}
        </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you must first load  script.js

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-10 editor" ng-controller="Editor">
          {{hello}}
        </div>
```